# Change static variable's value from a laravel php class

Tags: php, class, object, laravel-5

The below mentioned code works fine, but I want to set `public static $averageEvaluationCount = 3;` from database so that I can dynamically change the `$averageEvaluationCount`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use DateTime;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Post extends BaseDBModel
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $evalCountQuery = DB::table('averageEvaluations')->select('times')->get();
        $evalCounts = $evalCountQuery[0]->times;

    }

    public static $x = 3;
    protected $table = 'posts';
    public static $pointsPerKool = 10;
    public static $averageEvaluationValue = 8;
    public static $averageEvaluationCount = 3; //I want to change this value 3 to a value from database $evalCounts
    protected static $intervalForRedPoint = 1;
    public static $commentRequiredLowThreshold = 10;
    protected static $intervalForBluePoint = 3;
    protected static $rateThresholdToMarkAsGoldWithK = 8;
    protected static $daysToFreeze = 4320;
}
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: `self::$averageEvaluationCount = something;`

Comment: @MarkBaker The problem is when i  change "public static $averageEvaluationCount = 3;" to  public static $averageEvaluationCount = $evalCounts; it throws the following error: FatalErrorException in Post.php line 24:
Constant expression contains invalid operations

Comment: You can't do it in the property definition `declaration [of properties] may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.`, as per the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) - you have to do it in the constructor, where you're actually executing the database query to get the value

Comment: @RiggsFolly could you please suggest a little bit more where shall it put this self::$averageEvaluationCount = something; ?

Comment: Get one of your team to show you how to do it. Will be good for moral if you ask for help from one of them

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $evalCountQuery = DB::table('averageEvaluations')
        ->select('times')->get();
    self::$averageEvaluationCount = $evalCountQuery[0]->times;
}
```

OR

```
public function __construct()
{
    self::$averageEvaluationCount = DB::table('averageEvaluations')
        ->select('times')
        ->first()
        ->times;
}
```

Comment: OK, i have added the code as per your instruction like below, but still it's taking the hardcoded value from > this line: public static $averageEvaluationCount = 3;

`public function __construct()
 {
    $evalCountQuery = DB::table('averageEvaluations')
    ->select('times')->get();
    self::$averageEvaluationCount = 1;//$evalCountQuery[0]->times;
}`

Comment: How are you using it? `$post= new Post(); $theCount = $post::$averageEvaluationCount` should work. The construct has to be called first for the value to be changed.